# REGEX help for replacing a value

Tags: c#, regex

I have below Json which is having **-INF** in its value and I need to replace INF with "Infinity". Below is the sample JSON and REGEX which does the trick for me. I am looking for ways I can optimize the below method and if I can use a single Regex instead of two.

Sample Json : `"Power_dB":[-INF,-1000,-1000,-1000,-INF,-INF,-INF,-INF]`

My code:

```
                var pattern = @"-(INF){1},";
                var secondPattern = @"-(INF){1}\]";
                string replacement = "-Infinity,";
                string secondreplacement = "-Infinity]";
                string result = Regex.Replace( json, pattern, replacement );   
                result = Regex.Replace( result, secondPattern, secondreplacement );
                
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.Symbol };
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( result, settings ) ;
```

Above code gives me desired output as below:

`"Power_dB":["-INFINITY",-1000,-1000,-1000,"-INFINITY","-INFINITY","-INFINITY","-INFINITY"]`

Comment: Instead of capturing `,` and `]` you should use positive lookahead. Or capture them as a group and use a back reference to let it be part of the replacement string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest changing your expression to this:

```
-INF(?=[,\]])
```

Breaking it down:

- `-INF` - Match the literal "-INF"
- `(?=something)` - Positive lookahead. The expression only matches if this also matches, but this doesn't capture.
- `[,\]]` - Match `,` or `]`. In this case we have no modifier after it so it will only match a single character.

Then you can simply replace the matched part with this:

```
-Infinity
```

C# code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"-INF(?=[,\]])");
string input = "\"Power_dB\":[-INF,-1000,-1000,-1000,-INF,-INF,-INF,-INF]";
string result = regex.Replace(input, "-Infinity");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/QBZ91990)